# How to decide if a SearchResultEntry is a user or a group?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I am using LDAP search to find users and groups in active directory.

here is my search filter:

```
string Filter = "(|(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=person)(SAMAccountName=*))(&(objectCategory=group)(sAMAccountName=*)))";
```

I get a SearchResponse and I want to decide for every SearchResultEntry if it is a user or a group.

Is there an attribute I can check in order to decide if it is a user or a group?

Thanks, Inbal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used "objectClass" attribute which says "user" or "group"

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of "users" and groups within AD.

However something like this should be close:
if ((objectCategory=user)&&(objectClass=person))
{
   this is a user
}
else if ((objectClass=group))
{
   this is a group
}
else
{
   this is not a user or a group
}

You might find http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/LDAP%20Query%20Examples%20for%20AD useful.

-jim